# React showing value required on edit case even if the field is already populated

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, joi

I am using react-hook-form and Joi for the validataion in react. But in case of edit, if I don't touch any field and hit directly update, it shows value required, even when the field is already populated there.

But, once I focus or clicked on the input field, and hit update, then its get updated.

Here is the form:

```
const MarketplaceForm = ({ submitAction, submitBtnText, item }) => {
    //joi schema
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().required().min(3).max(191).label("Marketplace Name"),
    });

    //react hook form setup
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        setError,
        clearErrors,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm({
        resolver: joiResolver(schema),
    });

    const onSubmit = async (input) => {
        submitAction(input, setError);
    };

    return (
        <div className="intro-y box p-5">
            <form id="add_marketplace_form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="crud-form-1" className="form-label">
                        Marketplace Name
                    </label>
                    <input
                        className={`form-control w-full  ${
                            errors["name"] ? "border-red-500" : ""
                        }`}
                        type="text"
                        id="name"
                        name="name"
                        autoComplete="on"
                        {...register("name")}
                        defaultValue={item.name ?? ""}
                    />
                    <ErrorSpan errors={errors} fieldName="name" />
                </div>

                <div className="text-right mt-5">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-outline-secondary w-24 mr-1"
                    >
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success w-24">
                        {submitBtnText}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MarketplaceForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should check validation as your validation is not working properly or see the name props

is this default value working

```
defaultValue={item.name ?? ""}
```

Comment: yes its working, and even if i inspect that one field, it shows something like:

`<input class="form-control w-full  " type="text" id="name" name="name" autocomplete="on" value="accusantium">`

Comment: Can you create a codesanbox and send me a link so that We can solve it practically